# Error mostrar gráfico highcharts con data mediante variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, highcharts

Mediante `ajax` obtengo el dato que quiero mostrar en mi gráfico de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/grafico/3',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        graficoMedia(data);
    }
});
```

Este data me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, creo mi gráfico `solid gauge` de la siguiente manera:

```
function graficoMedia (array) {
$('#chart3').highcharts({
chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge'
},

title: null,

pane: {
    center: ['50%', '85%'],
    size: '140%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},

// the value axis
yAxis: {
    stops: [
        [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
        [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
    ],
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorTickInterval: null,
    tickAmount: 2,
    title: {
        y: -70
    },
    labels: {
        y: 16
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 15,
    title: {
        text: 'Media'
    }
},

plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
            y: 5,
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true
        }
    }
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [{
    name: 'Media',
    data: array[0].Media,
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
               '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">media</span></div>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' Media'
    }
}]
});
}
```

Pero este no se muestra correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero sin embargo si cambio mi campo `data` dentro de `series` de la siguiente forma:

```
series: [{
name: 'Media',
data: [4],
dataLabels: {
    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
           '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">media</span></div>'
},
tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' Media'
}
}]
```

Este si que funciona correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionarlo, he modificado la función `graficoMedia` tal que así:

```
function graficoMedia (array) {

var media = [];
media.push(parseFloat(array[0].media));

var chart = $('#chart').highcharts({
//merge: 'gaugeOptions',
chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge'
},

title: null,

pane: {
    center: ['50%', '85%'],
    size: '140%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
        innerRadius: '60%',
        outerRadius: '100%',
        shape: 'arc'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},

// the value axis
yAxis: {
    stops: [
        [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
        [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
        [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
    ],
    lineWidth: 0,
    minorTickInterval: null,
    tickAmount: 2,
    title: {
        y: -70
    },
    labels: {
        y: 16
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 15,
    /*title: {
        text: 'Media'
    }*/
},

plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
            y: 5,
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true
        }
    }
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [{
    name: 'Media',
    data: media,
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
               '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">Media</span></div>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' Media'
    }
}],

exporting: {
    enabled: false
}
});
}
```

Una vez recibido los datos por ajax, lo convierto en formato float y ya se los paso como `data` al gráfico.

Muchas gracias a la ayuda de @Héctor J. Orihuela Ruiz.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, en

```
series: [{
    name: 'Media',
    data: array[0].Media,
```

Tienes puesto data: array[0].Media, cuando lo que está esperando es un array de datos, por lo tanto debería ser:

```
series: [{
name: 'Media',
data: array,
```

Ya que le estarías pasando un array de datos.

Si no te funcionase así, haría un método que parsease el array de la respuesta a un array Javascript creado por ti, por si hubiese diferencias.

PD: Qué usas en el servidor para que te devuelva esa respuesta? podrías poner el código del servidor por favor?

Saludos

Comment: Ante todo, gracias por tu respuesta. En este gráfico, como puedes ver, solo necesito pasarle un dato para mostrar, sin ser necesario un array. También probé, directamente desde ajax antes de llamar a la función graficoMedia pasarle una variable que contenga este valor 'array[0].Media', pero aún así sigue sin funcionar. He probado también configurando 'data' con una función y dentro de ella devolver el dato array[0].Media, tampoco funciona. También lo he intentado como string, es decir, mediante la función devolver el dato "["+array[0].Media+"]" y nada. No sé cómo probar más.

Comment: Sí, comprendo que sólo necesites un dato pero según dice la página de HighCharts, la propiedad "data:" requiere un array, aunque sólo sea un número, de hecho tú mismo pones "data: [4]". Por lo tanto, yo haría dos cosas:
Primero, "console.log(data[0].Media);" en el success del ajax para comprobar que efectivamente así se accede al valor.

Segundo, create un array que no tenga nada que ver con el data de un número como el "[4]" y pásaselo como parámetro a la función "graficoMedia" y mira a ver si así lo pinta.

Comment: No me cabían más comentarios:

Tercero, si todo eso no funciona, prueba a realizar lo mismo de pasarle un array por parámetro fuera del success para ver si el tiempo de respuesta del servidor está influyendo.

Y no me des las gracias, es un placer ser de ayuda, a ver si lo sacamos :)

Comment: He realizado todas las pruebas que me comentas y obtengo los siguientes resultados: La primera me devuelve correctamente un 4. La segunda si creo el array dentro del success de `ajax` tampoco muestra nada. La tercera sí que funciona, si le paso un parámetro externo como vector, funciona tanto si ejecuto la función `graficoMedia` dentro del `success` como fuera del mismo. Por lo tanto, ¿qué puede estar ocurriendo? ¿El tiempo de respuesta en mi servidor es demasiado grande?

Comment: Disculpa la demora. Mi experiencia me dice que muchas veces cuando dependo de la respuesta ajax, por lo tanto, quizás haya que hacerle un sleep o controlarlo con un callback.

La siguiente prueba a realizar es poner un console.log dentro del método graficoMedia para ver qué es lo que llega, o bien depurándolo con las herramientas del navegador (F12). Ahí podrás comprobar el orden de ejecución, no sé si me explico. Ya me comentas qué tal.

Comment: Sigo con las pruebas y nada, no consigo arreglarlo. Ahora dentro del `data` de la función graficoMedia, es de la siguiente manera `data: (function () {
            console.log("Variable array.media: "+array[0].media);
            var res = [];
            res.push({
                    data: array[0].media,
                });
            return res;
        }()),`. En la consola me muestra correctamente la media, pero no la pinta en el gráfico. También compruebo el orden de ejecución y primero se ejecuta el `js` el cual llama a los diferente `ajax` con sus funciones.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo, y si pruebas a inicializar el gráfico y una vez esté creado usas el ajax y dentro del success haces esto? -> chart.series[0].setData(data); <-

Comment: ¿Puedes darme un poco más de detalles sobre cómo hacerlo? Lo he intentado creando una variable global chart, en mi función graficoMedia le asignó el gráfico a la variable chart. Luego en el 'document(ready)' llamo lo primero a la función graficoMedia y luego realizó el ajax con la indicación que me comentas, pero me da error. El primero con chart.series[0].setData(data) --> Cannot read property '0'. Luego si pongo esto chart.series.setData(data) --> Cannot read property 'serData'

Comment: var chart = Highcharts.charts[0]; chart.series[0].setData(data); (eso es lo que te da null?). Si no te va voy a crearme un ejemplo yo y si lo consigo realizar te doy mi resultado. Tenemos que sacarlo :)

Comment: Si, me sale que no existe la propiedad series

Comment: Solucionadooooo!! Mil graciaaaas!! Pongo la solución!!

Comment: Me alegro muchísimo, es un detalle simple pero si no lo sabes puedes volverte loco jeje.